# Creating a class that extends Array

Tags: arrays, typescript, class, extends

I am looking for a way to extend `Array` and spread the constructor args into `super`.

```
interface Token {
    name: string
}

class Nodes extends Array {
    constructor (v: Token[]) {
        super(...v)
    }
}

const n = new Nodes([{ name: 'Thomas ' }])
```

This is giving me issues. Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoHsDWETIN4BQyxyIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gQL4EEIA2cttyAOXQATCPwgAPSCGH8AglChwAnviIkE6EPSgBXBGHRRkACgBuNDNhABtALoBKNSRd1dAB2gmAdL7MP1YnZ2Ti16UmQAXlIIAHdBETETGzxSCmpkAHJUAAt0cl4s5FZHAiA).

I tried this as well:

```
interface Token {
    name: string
}

class Nodes extends Array {
    constructor (v: Token[]) {
        super()
        this.push(...v)
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, Object.create(Nodes.prototype));
    }
}

const n = new Nodes([{ name: 'Thomas ' }])

console.log(n)

n.map(v => console.log(v.name))
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
>      at new Nodes (eval at  (main-3.js:1239), :5:14)
>      at Nodes.map ()
>      at eval (eval at  (main-3.js:1239), :11:3)
>      at main-3.js:1239

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing the point but `Array` expects an integer as its constructor argument, it looks like you're trying to pass in `...Token[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Array constructor expects a number as an argument (length of the array). In your case it's possible to call `super()` without parameters and just push items later.

```
class Nodes extends Array {
    constructor(v: Token[]) {
        super();
        this.push(...v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
interface Token {
  name: string;
}

class Nodes extends Array<Token> {
  constructor (...tokens: Token[]) {
    super();
    this.push(...tokens);
  }
}

const n = new Nodes({ name: 'Thomas ' }, { name: 'Juan' });
console.log(n);
n.map(v => console.log(v.name));
```

Works well for me. :)